# How to call overridependingtransition on viewpager class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a view pager class.In that class onFling method i need to start a new activity with overridependingtransition.Is it possble? .If so then how.Please help me.

Comment: `start a new activity with overridependingtransition` .. `overridePendingTransition` is method of `Activity` . SO you only need current Activity's reference to call it ,,, Which you already i guess for building `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
val intent = Intent(mContext, XX::class.java)
mContext?.startActivity(intent)
mContext is a context 
But i need to know how i start "overridependingtransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.no_animation)" after calling startactivity.
by mcontext i can't do that right

Comment: You should provide a more detailed description of your problem and any code snippets of what you have and it's not working. As @ADM said the overridePendingTransition() method belongs to an Activity, therefore if you have a reference to the activity you can call it.

Answer (score 2):

You need `Context` of an Activity here not Application context. If `mContext` holds a reference to and `Activity` and declared as `mContext:Activity?` Then you can simply use:-

```
mContext?.overridePendingTransition()
```

if Its declared as `Context` You can cast it to Activity .

```
(mContext as Activity).overridePendingTransition()
```